# IoU (intersection over union) in 3 space in swift/arkit

Tags: augmented-reality, coremltools

I am using arkit and coreml for realtime object detection. Is thier a 3 space analog to IoU written in swift or a library to determine when two cubes overlap or two 3d objects overlap?

Here is a python code example I found for 2d Iou I would image it would be similar but for three space? Its not clear how to get z dimension out of a anchor object or any object from arkit. Has anyone tried to build a 3d version of IOU in swift and arkit?

```
def bb_intersection_over_union(boxA, boxB):
    # determine the (x, y)-coordinates of the intersection rectangle
    xA = max(boxA[0], boxB[0])
    yA = max(boxA[1], boxB[1])
    xB = min(boxA[2], boxB[2])
    yB = min(boxA[3], boxB[3])

    # compute the area of intersection rectangle
    interArea = max(0, xB - xA + 1) * max(0, yB - yA + 1)

    # compute the area of both the prediction and ground-truth
    # rectangles
    boxAArea = (boxA[2] - boxA[0] + 1) * (boxA[3] - boxA[1] + 1)
    boxBArea = (boxB[2] - boxB[0] + 1) * (boxB[3] - boxB[1] + 1)

    # compute the intersection over union by taking the intersection
    # area and dividing it by the sum of prediction + ground-truth
    # areas - the interesection area
    iou = interArea / float(boxAArea + boxBArea - interArea)

    # return the intersection over union value
    return iou
```

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?